# -E flag for sed

Tags: regex, sed

I seem to remember a *-E* flag for sed to enable extended regex, then looking in the man page today I see it's absent, however

```
echo development.properties | sed -E 's/(development.|staging.|qa.|production.)//'
```

properties

```
echo development.properties | sed 's/(development.|staging.|qa.|production.)//'
```

development.properties

```
echo development.properties | sed -r 's/(development.|staging.|qa.|production.)//'
```

properties

So it looks to me like *-E* is doing *something*, furthermore I'd venture to say it's now an alias for *-r*, at least that's what I thought *-E* was for (extended regex). Did it change at some point? It looks like it may still be supported for backwards compatibility, or no?

Also, it sounds like extended regex in sed [has nothing to do](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html) with ranges like the pipe character inside of parens, so why doesn't the substitution work without either of those flags (*-E*, *-r*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `-E` is an alias for `-r` in your sed version i.e. `extended regex support`
2. Without `extended regex` support, `square brackets` are matched as `literal parentheses` not for regex grouping.